# Missing accounts using java api

Tags: yodlee

The Yodlee Java API (10.2) is only returning 1 investment account for a particular user for Alliance Benefit Group of Illinois (CSID 14223). When accessing the same account via a Browser, the Quicken branded service or eMoney, 4 accounts are shown. The 4 accounts are Alliance Benefit Group Health Savings Master Plan, XYZ Company 401(k) Plan, HSA Test Plan, Refreshment Services Inc. The Yodlee API is only showing the holdings for first account.

CSID 14223 was successfully added as a service (itemId=19433358). The following code snippet is showing only 1 account:

```
DataExtent dataExtent = new DataExtent();
dataExtent.setStartLevel(0);
dataExtent.setEndLevel(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

ItemSummary is = Util.getDataService().getItemSummaryForItem1(myContext,
            new Long(19433358l), dataExtent);

com.yodlee.soap.core.dataservice.ItemData id = is.getItemData();
List accountsList = id.getAccounts();
Object[] accounts = accountsList.getElements();
System.out.println("Number of Accounts: "+accounts.length);
```

What's going on? Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with the API?
Bruce Thompson
Perspective Partners, LLC.

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a service request using Yodlee customer care tool and provide below details in the service request for further investigation -

1. CobrandID
2. ItemID
3. Issue description